# Throwing a File not found exception after writing to an excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi

So I take in a list of Doubles and am writing them to an existing excel sheet. As far as I can tell I have no problem opening the file, creating the new cells and adding the data. However as soon as the loop completes that is setting the new Cell value I throw a file not found exception.

I've stared at this and tried different things for a few days now and just can't see what's wrong.

List input is 29 numbers positive and negative.

Here is the full function. Loop in question will be added again below full code block.

```
private static void ocrAddToExcel(List list, List Ion){

        String templatePath = "/Users/pluebbert/NetBeansProjects/PDFtoExcel/OCR_Excel_Template.xls";
        System.out.println("Template: " + templatePath);

        File input = new File(templatePath);

         List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<>();


         for(int i = 0; i <= list.size()-1; i++){

            Double conc = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).toString());
            System.out.println(conc);
            doubleList.add(conc);

         }

         try{
             if(input.exists()){
                 System.out.println("Found input stream file");
                 System.out.println(input.getAbsolutePath());
             }

             FileInputStream template = new FileInputStream(input);
             System.out.println("FIS Created");

             HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(template);
             System.out.println("Grabbed book");
             HSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);

             int firstNum = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); //0
             int lastNum = sheet.getLastRowNum(); //33


             System.out.println("First num: " + firstNum + " lastNum:" + lastNum);

                  //THIS LOOP BELOW//
             for(int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++){

                  Double conc = doubleList.get(i);

                  System.out.println("Conc: " + conc + " I:::: " + i + "n::: " + n);

                  Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).createCell(i, n);
                  cell.setCellValue(conc);

                  System.out.println(cell.toString());

                     //Loop completes and prints every cell correctly
             }



             //Print below never gets executed.

             System.out.println("Done adding data to cells for pdf number: " + n);

             System.out.println("Iterator done");

             String destinationPath = isEmpty ? "Test" + "_" + "Test" + "_Ions.xls" : outputName + ".xls";
             // if empty, use default name, else user specified name
             File outputFile = new File(destinationPath);
             System.out.println("Created output file at: " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

             FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); //saves file

             book.write(fileOut);
             fileOut.flush();
             template.close();
             fileOut.close();


            ++n;

            System.out.println("*************Template filled*************");
            System.out.println("Now renaming file for you");

            fileOut.close();
            open(destinationPath);
         }


         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("File not found");
         }
    }
```

So after the loop completes and prints all the correct cell value's to the console I get the file not found exception.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++){

                  Double conc = doubleList.get(i);

                  System.out.println("Conc: " + conc + " I:::: " + i + "n::: " + n);

                  Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).createCell(i, n);
                  cell.setCellValue(conc);

                  System.out.println(cell.toString());

                     //Loop completes and prints every cell correctly
             }
```

Comment: you might try creating more try/catch loops that encompass fewer lines of code to identify the line of code that is causing your error.

Comment: Add this line `e.printStackTrace();` inside your catch statement so you can see the exception stack trace. And add the Exception Stack Trace in the question. Your try block may have failed in many places that do not necessarily mean that a 'File is not found' (e.g. `book.write(fileOut);` throws an IOException. Also you close the fileOut stream twice.

Comment: Thank you @IoannisBarakos, I can't believe I forgot to stack trace it. It was a simple out of index when I looped over my list.

Comment: System.out is buffered so don't use absence of output to indicate precisely how far program has progressed.  `new FileOutputStream` can throw `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
if(input.exists()){
   System.out.println("Found input stream file");
   System.out.println(input.getAbsolutePath());
}
FileInputStream template = new FileInputStream(input);
```

This last line is throwing FileNotFoundException.
Instead you should create your new workbook:

```
HSSFWorkbook book=new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet=book.createSheet("FirstSheet"); 
HSSFRow row=sheet.createRow(0);
cell.setCellValue(conc);
```

and so on.